# Bibliography, Reference section

Tags: bibliographies, citing

writing my research proposal, have trouble to define the reference section at the end of the my latex file, I export `.bib` file from JabRef, and the Latex upload the `.bib` file well, but when I run the Latex I don't see the Reference section at the end, however I haven't cited any reference in the passage. I have run the Latex several times haven'y seen the ref section yet. When I cite a ref in the passage, in the output pdf file it gives me the question mark.

This is how I call the `*.bib` file

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Research Proposal}
```

Comment: Are you really using the `biblatex` package?  `\bibliographystyle{<style>}` is not a `biblatex` command.  But, regardless, your problem sounds like you are not running the normal sequence of `latex file.tex`, `bibtex file.aux`, `latex file.tex`, `latex file.tex` (where 'file.tex' is the name of your actual `.tex` file).

Comment: @jon - I don't think it's necessary -- or advisable -- to include "`.aux`" in the bibtex-ing instruction; `bibtex file` suffices.

Comment: Did you write `\nocite{*}`? This is the canonical way to make every item of the .bib file appear in the Reference section, even if it is not cited in  the text.

Comment: @Mico -- It is advisable at this stage: otherwise people may try things like `bibtex bibliography.bib`, which I've certainly seen before. It may not be necessary, but why not let people know which file is getting processed?

Comment: @jon -- Just to be clear: I recommend writing `bibtex file` rather than `bibtex file.aux`. If there's a risk of confusion over which file(s) BibTeX operates on, it may be necessary to state explicitly that one must not run `bibtex somefile.bib`.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments, actually I'm using \usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib}, so don't have problem with \bibliographystyle{<style>} command, also I used \nocite{*} but nothing happened, based on the Latex Log file the problem is with aux file, Dose Latex generate .aux file after running BibTex or I need to generate .aux file with JabRef, when I am generating the bib file?

Comment: This is the Log file message when I run BibTex: 

[ This is BibTex, The top-level auxiliary file: proposal.aux The style file plain.bst  White space in argument--line 14 of plain Proposal.aux :\bibdata{Ref:Test} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no database files--while reading file proposal.aux warning-- I didn't fid a database entry for "AbedonHymanThomas2003" (There were two error messages).]

Comment: When you run `latex file.tex` (or `latex file` -- it is clever enough to look for the file extension itself), it will, on a successful run, create `file.aux`, which is the 'target' file that BibTeX reads (via `bibtex file.aux` or `bibtex file` -- BibTeX, too, is clever).  What happens, briefly, is that when LaTeX reads the command `\cite{<bibkey>}`, it writes in the `.aux` file that that citation was cited; BibTeX then writes information to a file ending `.bbl`, which LaTeX then uses to write the correct information to the outputted `.dvi` or `.pdf`.